# Yet another MVVM and Opening/Closing of Dialog discussion - Code Behind

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dialog, code-behind

Why is having some code behind for doing simple operations such as opening or closing a dialog a bad design choice when using MVVM? If not for code behind, then where is the consistency for handling such a simple problem such as opening a dialog in MVVM?

I know this subject has probably been beaten to death and using "Code Behind" in WPF has been getting a lot bad rep over the years. I just want to make my point here and hopefully it helps someone gain a different perspective on the problem.

I think most people would agree that the MVVM pattern while a little bloated encourages reuse and better testable code. Separating business logic from the view is not a new concept but yet many people still don't do it. MVVM and WPF makes this separation a bit easier through the concepts of data binding and allows your ViewModels and business logic to be tested independent of the view.

Where it breaks down is when the developer needs to do simple things like opening or closing a dialog. Outside of MVVM, a developer could just instantiate the view, assign the DataContext and call ShowDialog. But in MVVM, a developer's first thought always goes to what's the common pattern here for opening/closing dialogs through MVVM. And what do they do, they take their question to Google/Bing/StackOverflow. And sure enough, they find answers to their question but the problem is there is no consistency here for doing such a simple operation. Some people want to use Mediators, others a dialog service, and others want to bring in Prism. Just about everyone has their own home grown implementation and all to accomplish what? So that they can avoid having "Code-Behind"? To me that is just sad. We've basically taken something that is so simple to do and added abstractions and indirection to try to solve the problem. The gain is so small it's not even worth it. Without going through this level indirection, you can still reuse your ViewModels with other Views, and you can still test your ViewModels in isolation. The only thing you don't get to test is a couple lines of code that opens or closes a dialog.

The MVVM and unit testing purists will think this is blasphemy. But remember, in the end, it's really your decision on how complex you want to make your application. To me the simple solution is usually the right solution.

Comment: Sorry but SO is for **questions** and this isn't one.

Comment: You can still put View-Specific code behind in MVVM. You can still instantiate the window manually and call `ShowDialog()`. In spite of that, I implemented a kind of "Window Factory" because my MVVM is targeted towards multi-platform, and not just WPF. Then I can have some properties at the VM level which define how (if) a window is supposed to be shown for that VM at that point. and the Factory (which is abstract and has a concrete implementation for each of the supported platforms) takes care of the rest.

Comment: I don't think this is a bloated design, it's just a matter of scalability. My previous design was much simpler but it was too tied to WPF, so I had to re-do it in order to decouple from WPF and be able to support multiple UI platforms / frameworks.

Comment: To really understand why MVVM is better, you had to have worked on large scale/enterprise winforms solutions, where your code behind file was 10k+ lines of madness.

Comment: Added the question. You happy now? As all of your comments, I'm not saying MVVM is bad but it does have flaws. Sometimes, you focus so much effort on not breaking the tenets of MVVM that usually there's a simpler way to do things. And yes Jim, I have worked on large scale winform solutions. I understand the pain of code behind. But to say that you can't have any code behind is absurd.

Comment: The rule isn't "no codebehind", it's "no mixing UI and data". Usually that will result in "no codebehind". Code-behind is perfectly acceptable for doing UI related things.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is having some code behind for doing simple operations such as opening or closing a dialog a bad design choice when using MVVM?

It's not and anyone who tells you otherwise does not understand the central objective of MVVM.

> If not for code behind, then where is the consistency for handling such a simple problem such as opening a dialog in MVVM?

Consistency regarding a specific problem is not something a general pattern like MVVM can or needs to provide. There is no right way to do it, among other aspects there are simply ways that violate the MVVM and those that do not.